# How to format strings in Scala?

Tags: scala

I need to print a formatted string containing scala.Long.
java.lang.String.format() is incompatible with scala.Long (compile time) and RichLong (java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException)

Compiler warns about deprecation of Integer on the following working code:

```
val number:Long = 3243
String.format("%d", new java.lang.Long(number))
```

Should I change fomatter, data type or something else?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
val number: Long = 3243
"%d".format(number)
```

Comment: There's also value in explaining **why** this should be the case.

Comment: `.format` in this case will be the method of `StringLike` which is implicitly created from string literal.

Answer (score 22):

The format method in Scala exists directly on **instances** of String, so you don't need/want the static class method.  You also don't need to manually box the `long` primitive, let the compiler take care of all that for you!

```
String.format("%d", new java.lang.Integer(number))
```

is therefore better written as

```
"%d".format(number)
```

Answer (score 7):

@Bruno's answer is what you should use in most cases.

If you must use a Java method to do the formatting, use

```
String.format("%d",number.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])
```

which will box the `Long` nicely for Java.

Comment: This works. Do you know why this won't cause a runtime error like with my RichLong approach?

Comment: `RichLong` is, to Java, just some random class.  Java expects to see a boxed primitive integer corresponding to `"%d"`.  So of course Java throws a fit when it gets a `RichLong`.  The `asInstanceOf[AnyRef]` preferentially boxes into the `java.lang` class, not the `Rich` class.