# What is the proper way to format a double in a Play 2 template

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

Here is my abbreviated code from a Play 2 template...

```
@(variable: com.mypackage.Variable) 

<div class='statsbody'>
    <div class='statsform'>
        <label>Average:</label>
        <span>@"%.2f".format(variable.getAverage())</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I get a compile error:

```
`identifier' expected but `"' found
```

and I got the idea above from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989243/how-to-format-strings-in-scala), which says how to do it at the scala command prompt, which is great, but doesn't work in a template.

The `getAverage()` method belongs to an external Java package I am using and it returns a raw `double`.  This all works fine and without the formatting I can happily display the right numbers.

I have tried a variety of alternatives including using the static Java String formatting method...

```
@String.format("%.2f", variable.getAverage())
```

...which gave

```
Overloaded method value [format] cannot be applied to (String, Double)
```

So my question is, what is the proper way to format a double in a Play 2 template?  I know I could probably use Javascript, but I'd like to know if there's a Play/Scala solution to this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use brackets:

```
@("%.2f".format(variable.getAverage()))
```

or:

```
@{
  "%.2f".format(variable.getAverage())
  //more scala code
}
```

which allows you to write multi-statement  scala code in template.

Answer (score 0):

I have found *an* answer, but it doesn't directly address the question at hand.  I can get the `String.format` code to work if I box the `double` into a `java.lang.Double` like this...

```
@String.format("%.2f", new java.lang.Double(variable.getAverage()))
```

This solves my problem for now, but doesn't really answer the question.  There must be a Scala/Play solution... mustn't there?

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I found to properly change user's language and apply formatting to numbers is:

In Controller:

```
public Result lang(String lang) {
    changeLang(lang);
    Logger.debug("Language change request: " + lang);
    return redirect(routes.Dashboard.dashboard());
}
```

In template we use following:

```
 <td>@("%.2f".formatLocal(lang().toLocale(), variable.getAverage()))</td>
```