# Printing with variable length width

Tags: scala

In C, I could write,

```
int width = 5;
int number = 10;
printf("%*d", width, number); //output: "   10"
```

I see that Scala could do,

```
val number = 10
print(f"$number%5d") //output: "   10"
```

But I would like to pass the width in as a variable, is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989243/how-to-format-strings-in-scala

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can only offer an alternative:

```
val number = 10
val width = 5
printf(s"%${width}d", number)
```

It seems that there is no exact equivalent of C printf in Scala.